# MATLink: MEngine compilation error

Tags: matlink

Following the instructions in the [MATLink website](http://matlink.org/troubleshooting/) I am posting my issue when compiling MEngine on a Linux machine. I have checked that `csh`, `g++` and `libuuid` are properly installed. I am trying to link Mathematica 13.0.0 with MATLAB R2018a. According to [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/content/dam/mathworks/mathworks-dot-com/support/sysreq/files/SystemRequirements-Release2018a_SupportedCompilers.pdf), the compiler supported is `gcc 6.3.x`. I have tried `gcc version 6.4.0 20180424 (Ubuntu 6.4.0-17ubuntu1)` and `gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)` (I have been unable to download any lower version), and both throw the same error. Here are the details:

```
In[2]:= MATLink`Developer`GetInfo[]

MATLink 1.1 for Unix (Fri 15 Aug 2014)

13.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)

csh:
/bin/csh

g++:
/usr/bin/g++

MATLAB:
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018a/bin

libuuid:
    libuuid.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1
    libuuid.so.1 (libc6) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1
    libuuid.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so

System PATH:
/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/13.0/Executables
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/sbin
/usr/bin
/sbin
/bin
/usr/games
/usr/local/games
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018a/bin
/snap/bin
/home/apozas/mosek/8/tools/platform/linux64x86/bin
```

Error:

```
make -f Makefile.lin64
g++ -O -Wall -I/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/13.0/Executables/../SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/Linux-x86-64/CompilerAdditions -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018a/bin/../extern/include -L/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/13.0/Executables/../SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/Linux-x86-64/CompilerAdditions -L/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018a/bin/../bin/glnxa64 menginetm.cpp mengine.cpp set.cpp get.cpp main.cpp -Wl,-rpath-link,/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018a/bin/../bin/glnxa64/ -DMLINTERFACE=3 -lML64i3 -luuid -lmx -leng -o mengine
In file included from menginetm.cpp:9:
/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/13.0/Executables/../SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/Linux-x86-64/CompilerAdditions/mathlink.h:116:22: error: stray ‘\’ in program
  116 | /*\ syntax\ error\ */\ )
      |                      ^
/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/13.0/Executables/../SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/Linux-x86-64/CompilerAdditions/mathlink.h:116:24: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘)’ token
  116 | /*\ syntax\ error\ */\ )
      |                        ^
/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/13.0/Executables/../SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/Linux-x86-64/CompilerAdditions/mathlink.h:544:2: error: ‘wint’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘_wint’?
  544 |  wint low, hi;
      |  ^~~~
      |  _wint
In file included from mlp.h:11,
                 from mengine.h:11,
                 from mengine.cpp:8:
/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/13.0/Executables/../SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/Linux-x86-64/CompilerAdditions/mathlink.h:116:22: error: stray ‘\’ in program
  116 | /*\ syntax\ error\ */\ )
      |                      ^
In file included from mlp.h:11,
                 from mengine.h:11,
                 from mengine.cpp:8:
/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/13.0/Executables/../SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/Linux-x86-64/CompilerAdditions/mathlink.h:116:24: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘)’ token
  116 | /*\ syntax\ error\ */\ )
      |                        ^
/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/13.0/Executables/../SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/Linux-x86-64/CompilerAdditions/mathlink.h:544:2: error: ‘wint’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘_wint’?
  544 |  wint low, hi;
      |  ^~~~
      |  _wint
In file included from mlp.h:11,
                 from mengine.h:11,
                 from set.cpp:8:
/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/13.0/Executables/../SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/Linux-x86-64/CompilerAdditions/mathlink.h:116:22: error: stray ‘\’ in program
  116 | /*\ syntax\ error\ */\ )
      |                      ^
In file included from mlp.h:11,
                 from mengine.h:11,
                 from set.cpp:8:
/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/13.0/Executables/../SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/Linux-x86-64/CompilerAdditions/mathlink.h:116:24: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘)’ token
  116 | /*\ syntax\ error\ */\ )
      |                        ^
/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/13.0/Executables/../SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/Linux-x86-64/CompilerAdditions/mathlink.h:544:2: error: ‘wint’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘_wint’?
  544 |  wint low, hi;
      |  ^~~~
      |  _wint
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/cassert:44,
                 from set.cpp:13:
set.cpp: In function ‘void eng_make_Struct()’:
set.cpp:192:39: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘size_t’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} and ‘int’ [-Wsign-compare]
  192 |     assert(mxGetNumberOfElements(var) == len);
      |            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
In file included from mlp.h:11,
                 from mengine.h:11,
                 from get.cpp:8:
/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/13.0/Executables/../SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/Linux-x86-64/CompilerAdditions/mathlink.h:116:22: error: stray ‘\’ in program
  116 | /*\ syntax\ error\ */\ )
      |                      ^
In file included from mlp.h:11,
                 from mengine.h:11,
                 from get.cpp:8:
/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/13.0/Executables/../SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/Linux-x86-64/CompilerAdditions/mathlink.h:116:24: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘)’ token
  116 | /*\ syntax\ error\ */\ )
      |                        ^
/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/13.0/Executables/../SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/Linux-x86-64/CompilerAdditions/mathlink.h:544:2: error: ‘wint’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘_wint’?
  544 |  wint low, hi;
      |  ^~~~
      |  _wint
In file included from mlp.h:11,
                 from mengine.h:11,
                 from main.cpp:8:
/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/13.0/Executables/../SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/Linux-x86-64/CompilerAdditions/mathlink.h:116:22: error: stray ‘\’ in program
  116 | /*\ syntax\ error\ */\ )
      |                      ^
/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/13.0/Executables/../SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/Linux-x86-64/CompilerAdditions/mathlink.h:116:24: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘)’ token
  116 | /*\ syntax\ error\ */\ )
      |                        ^
/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/13.0/Executables/../SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/Linux-x86-64/CompilerAdditions/mathlink.h:544:2: error: ‘wint’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘_wint’?
  544 |  wint low, hi;
      |  ^~~~
      |  _wint
make: *** [Makefile.lin64:21: mengine] Error 1
```

The error is the same when using `g++` 6 and 9. I also tried the solution suggested [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/220320/matlink-bug-when-compiling-mengine), without success.

Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: I am able to build the binary with the following compiler flag: CFLAGS = -Wall -DMX_COMPAT_32 on RHEL 8.2, Lustre 2.12.6_ddn51 while using MMA 13 and Matlab 2021a. I get the same compiler errors without invoking the compiler flag. Nevertheless, the build lets crash Matlab, hence for my configuration MATLink is at the moment useless. Let me know if it works for Matlab R2018a.

Comment: This did not work for me. Adding the flag -DMX_COMPAT_32 did not change the error message in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After posting an issue on [Github](https://github.com/rsmenon/MATLink/issues/115), I got the following guidance, which worked without problem.

> szhorvat on Github:
>
> Edit Makefile.lin64 and:
>
> - Add -DMX_COMPAT_32 to CFLAGS
> - Remove -DMLINTERFACE=3
> - Replace -lML64i3 by -lML64i4

Comment: Thanks for posting it! I didn't see the question here on SE. Unfortunately, we don't have a lot of time to work on MATLink anymore.

Comment: That makes your quick response even more valuable. Thank you very much for the assistance. Honestly, if you hadn't provided a solution, I would have downgraded my version of Mathematica. I'd rather keep using MATLink than have the latest MMA. So thanks also for the software.